# Execute a stored procedure using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-insert

This is my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_addUser
     @UserName nvarchar(50),    
     @Prenom nvarchar(50),  
     @Nom nvarchar(50), 
     @Mail nvarchar(50),    
     @Password char(8), 
     @Addresse nvarchar(100),   
     @Ville nvarchar(50),   
     @Province nvarchar(50),    
     @PostalCode char(6),
     @Pays nvarchar(50),    
     @AnimalGenre nvarchar(50), 
     @NomAnimal nvarchar(50),   
     @Race nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Client
   VALUES (@UserName,@Prenom,@Nom,@Mail,@Password,@Addresse,@Ville,@Province,@PostalCode,@Pays,@AnimalGenre,@NomAnimal,@Race);
END
```

I think this ok for the stored Procedure

Now the code to add value in Data Base

```
Sub sp_addUser()

    Dim intRowsAff As Integer

    lblErrMsg.Text = ""
    lblRecsAff.Text = ""

    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_addUser", con)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUserName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prenom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPrenom.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nom", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtNom.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mail", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtMail.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.Char, 8).Value = txtPass.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Addresse", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtAdresse.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ville", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtVille.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Province", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtProvince.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.Char, 6).Value = txtPostal.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pays", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtPays.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnimalGenre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = rblAnimal.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NomAnimal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtAnimal.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Race", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtRace.Text

    Try
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        intRowsAff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblErrMsg.Text = ex.Message & ex.Source
    End Try
    lblRecsAff.Text = intRowsAff & " record(s) inserted"
    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

After I execute the method VS said that I have to much specified arguments for the  procedure sp_addUser

I don't understand why this generate error!

Comment: did you remember to update stored procedure definition in DB?

Comment: What you mean whit update stored procedure definition??

Comment: I rename my SP to spAddUser and restart VS and this Is work well now Thank's

Comment: There is absolutely *zero* need for this to be a stored proc.  Back in the day when we didnt have parameterized queries, yes, but today its just a waste.  Its a TON of sunk time in creation and maintenance of something that serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @Dan-o, it has nothing to do with answer the OP question, and its arguable the exact opposite. I put no inline SQL in my code simply because then if a data change needs to be made, I could easily updte the stored procedure and the work is done.

Comment: @logixologist: It comes down to perspective I suppose. From my perspective most changes that occur in the data layer involve a schema change. This typically bubbles all the way back up to the application code.  So for the vast majority of situations the "data change" argument doesn't save anything.

Comment: @Dan-o and I see db changes to be many times simply stored procedure changes that are not schema related. Tomayto Tomahto Potayto Potahto :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code and stored procedure you posted appear to be in sync.

That strongly suggests that the stored procedure in the Database is out of sync with what you expect in your code. Suggest you check what you posted is actually the stored procedure in DB.

Also Note: you should not prefix your proc with 'sp_' unless it natually resides in master.

Comment: I rename my SP to spAddUser and restart VS and this Is work well now Thank's

Answer (score 3):

### just sync your Sp with code behind method and set parameters as sp.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sqlpr1 As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "[sp_ItemPackingList]"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateDate.Text.Trim()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Thk", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPendQty.Text.Trim()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPendQty.Text.Trim()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
        obj.GetDataTable("[sp_ItemPackingList]", sqlpr1)

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
   With con
       .ConnectionString = sqlConnectionString
       .Open()
   End With
   With cmd
       .CommandText = "UpdateProcedure"
       .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("CName", txtCName.Text)
       .Parameters(0).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("CAddress",txtCAddress1.Text)
       .Parameters(1).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
       .Parameters.AddWithValue("CCity", txtCCity)
       .Parameters(2).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
       .ExecuteNonSqlQuery()
    End With
Catch ex As Exception

Finally
  cmd.Dispose()
  con.Close()
End Try
```