# How to specify date format used by ADO.NET when passing it to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, parameter-passing, date-conversion

I am using ADO.NET to pass a datetime parameter to a stored procedure and I am getting

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime

on servers configured with `DATEFORMAT ydm`.

I have a simple stored procedure (it just takes a parameter and do nothing):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestDate]
    @date AS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END
```

I am executing it with ADO.NET by using datetime parameter:

```
Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime
param.Value = New Date(2021, 1, 13)
```

Execution on the SQL side looks like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.TestDate @date = @date', N'@date datetime', @date = '2021-01-13 00:00:00.000'
```

and it works on most of our servers. Unfortunately one of our clients has different configuration. I have simulated this by adding `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` to previous execution, so when it runs it throws

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime

```
SET DATEFORMAT ydm;

EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.TestDate @date = @date', N'@date datetime', @date = '2021-01-13 00:00:00.000'
```

It seems like ADO.NET passes dates in a ODBC format which is sensitive to dateformat / language setting. Do you have some idea how to overcome this issue? (I have tried passing dates as strings in ISO 8601 format and it works with this example, but some of our other queries have other issues with that and I don't like this kind of "dirty tricks").

Edit:

Thanks for replies, I have checked sp code once more. I have further simplified the example: I have captured execution of real procedure with profiler on the client server and I have deleted all "noise code". On client environment (from application and Management Studio) I am getting

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime

(which can be simulated by setting dateformat: SET DATEFORMAT dmy - I have checked it from DBCC USEROPTIONS):

```
exec sp_executesql N'',N'@date datetime',@date='2021-01-27 10:04:55.263'
```

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values. This isn't something to be debated. Problems occur *ONLY* if dates are converted to strings or stored in string fields. `Error converting data type varchar to datetime` this means that code you didn't post tried to convert the date into a string. The stored procedure you posted does nothing, so it can't throw anything

Comment: `ADO.NET passes dates in a ODBC format ` no it doesn't. There's no such thing. All protocols pass parameters outside the query, as binary parameters to the RPC call to the server.

Comment: This is always a code bug. To get help with this, you need to post the actual code, actual stored procedure and actual table schema (ie the `CREATE TABLE` statement). Typically, you need to post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` but in this case, the problem is clearly in the server-side code

Comment: You set `DATEFORMAT` as `ydm` and you pass in `2021-01-13`. it is treating `13` as month which is invalid. You should use `ISO` date format `2021-01-13T00:00:00` or `20210113`

Comment: @Squirrel the OP didn't post any database calling code at all. The `EXEC sp_executesql  ...` is (supposedly) the server-side capture, where date-typed parameters are shown in an ISOis form. This is no problem UNLESS the actual query uses string concatenation *inside* the query, and what we see is the actual string sent to the database

Comment: that is not true `ISO form`. with dateformat as `ydm`, `2021-01-13` will gives error. If `@date` is declare as `DATE` that will be alright

Comment: @Martin post your actual VB.NET code, and SQL not a "simplified" example. Dates have no format. Period. Your code has a bug. Either the VB.NET code, or the stored procedure, uses string concatenation.

Comment: When `SET DATEFORMAT ydm;` is in effect datetime values parsed from strings assume year-day-month, so it's trying to parse `2021-01-13 00:00:00.000` as the 1st day of the 13th month, 2021. Try using an ISO string instead, `2021-01-13T00:00:00.000`, which bypasses that little parsing issue.

Comment: @Martin if you used `varr cmd=new SqlCommand("TestDate",connection); cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; cmd.Params.Add(...); cmd.ExecuteNonQuerry();` you'd get no string conversions and no errors. Clearly, you didn't. You haven't even posted any coded that shows the use of parameterized queries.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there are no formats involved when using parameters. Despite the OP's claims, the actual code isn't using parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when using SqlParameters with the correct data types, I agree. The sp_executesql example is parsing strings, though.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning which means the OP is still using string concatenation and after 1 hour, still hasn't posted the actual query. It would be easy to fix the problem without formats, but without the code, we can only guess and point to the docs and duplicates like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663940/execute-a-stored-procedure-using-vb-net)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning What OP has posted is quite clearly a server-side trace of an ad-hoc batch `EXEC dbo.TestDate @date = @date`, this just shows the equivalent code you can run in SSMS, it **does not** mean that is the code that is actually being run. Parameters are passed in using TDS parameter binding, and are binary, that text simply does not appear anywhere.

Comment: @Martin, it looks like the `sp_executesql` statement was captured by a SQL trace. The trace does not show the actual internal binary format of the date but rather a reverse-engineered string version of the value. [Profiler has a bug](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-trace-parameter-values-are-not-always-as-they-seem/) where it doesn't build a proper ISO 8601 datetime to avoid a DATEFORMAT dependency. You mentioned a different configuration but that shouldn't matter, although the correct parameter date data  type should be specified regardless.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, problem was not connected with dates. My colleague who send me information about the issue gave me only the profiler output and error message from the MMS, he didn't mentioned that the application was throwing "string or binary data would be truncated". I thought that dates are serialized as string and I have created these examples to show the issue (I was sure that application was throwing date conversion error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates have no format, they're binary values. In .NET `DateTime` uses a tick count field internally. SQL Server uses several date types, none of which is based, parsed or stored as a string. ADO.NET passes parameters as separate, binary parameters to the RPC call to the server.

One way or the other the data access code that's missing is converting dates to strings instead of using parameterized queries.

This code wouldn't convert dates to strings or need parsing on the server:

```
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Using cmd As New SqlCommand("TestDate", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = New Date(2021, 1, 13)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The type could be any of the date types, eg: `SqlDbType.DateTime`, `SqlDbType.DateTime2` or `SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset`. The type that best matches the stored procedure parameter is `Date`

**What about SSMS ?**

In SSMS the queries are written as *text*. Even a parameter declaration in the end uses text. You need to provide the correct date literal to avoid localization issues.

`datetime` is a legacy type that's affected by `DATEFORMAT` unless a full ISO8601 string or an unseparated `YYYYMMDD` string is used. This means that `YYYY-MM-DD` can be parsed as `YYYY-DD-MM` **if** *datetime is used*.

The newer types don't have this problem. `date`, the correct type for this  parameter and `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset` all recognize `YYYY-MM-DD` no matter what `DATEFORMAT` is.